# Exposed date filter against >= "today" fails until 5pm Mountain time

Tags: 8, views, datetime

- I added a `Date only` date field named `expires` to the user profile.
- The `expires` field has the value **2021-01-08** for a certain user (I checked the database; it has no time component).
- In a view, I have an exposed filter that tests the `expires` field using Operator=`Is greater than or equal to` with Value type=`An offset from the current time` and Value=`today`.
- On **2021-01-09** up until 5pm Mountain time, the user with `expires` = **2021-01-08** is improperly included in the view.
- When I refresh the view at 5pm Mountain time or thereafter, the user is dropped from the view.
- I tried switching to Value type=`A date in any machine readable format` and Value=`today`. This also has a problem, but in this case users aren't included when they should be sometimes (the problem is sort of reversed).
- If, as a test, I edit the exposed filter and use Value type=`A date in any machine readable format` and Value=**2021-01-09** (i.e. hardcode the date) then the user with `expires`=**2021-01-08** is not included in the view at any time, as expected.

It appears that `today` isn't giving me today's date until 5pm Mountain Time. What am I missing?

SOLUTION: Inspired by @Patrick Kenny below, I added this to MYMODULE.views_execution.inc:

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter($view, $query)
{
    if (!empty($query->where[1]['conditions'])) {
        foreach ($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $key => &$value) {
            error_log($value['field']);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing on 2021-01-13 at 10:17 am Mountain Time with Operator=`Is greater than or equal to` and Value type=`An offset from the current time` and Value=`today`, the output is

`DATE_FORMAT(user__field_expire.field_expire_value, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT('2021-01-12T17:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Notice the `today` value of 2021-01-12T17:00:00. **WRONG DAY**. Off by 7 hours. This confirms the answer by @Patrick Kenny.

HOWEVER, if I change to Value=`now` (instead of Value=`today`) and test again, the output is

`DATE_FORMAT(user__field_expire.field_expire_value, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT('2021-01-13T10:17:02', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Notice the `today` value of 2021-01-13T10:17:02. **CORRECT DAY** and time.

In my case, switching to `now` seems adequate to fix the problem because the Y-m-d format is applied, making the comparison work correctly. But I still subscribe to @Patrick Kenny's solution as a general fix.

Comment: What's the timezone set on the server?  Is a default timezone set for the Drupal site?  If you are logged in as a user, is a separate timezone set for the user?  What time does Drupal see with `\Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime()`?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Patrick Kenny. On the server, `timedatectl` showed `Local time` `Mon 2021-01-11 09:27:21 MST` (my time when I issued the command). `Time zone` showed America/Denver (my time zone). In Drupal under Regional settings, `Default time zone` is set to Denver (my time zone) and `Users may set their own time zone` is off.  This code `error_log("currentTime=".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime()));` displayed `21-01-11 09:44:19 currentTime=2021-01-11 09:44:19` (the time when I refreshed the page). So, everything looks right. That's why I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the server timezone, Drupal timezone, and `\Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime()` are all pointing to the same time, you have probably been bitten by the same bug in Views that I was, [Date/time Views filter tries strotime() relative to Unix epoch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2647292).

Basically, all relative values like "today" "yesterday - 5 hours", etc. can have timezone issues in Views.  [There's another related issue I reported as well](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3171554).  This bug has yet to be fixed.

In my case, I needed to filter by "midnight of the current day", and Views was giving me incorrect results depending on the timezone.

I fixed it like this (code more or less pasted directly from my site, but it should give you an idea of what you can do):

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if (($view->id() === 'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME') &&
    ($display_id === 'page_1')) {
    $filters = $view->display_handler->getOption('filters');
    if ($filters['field_MY_FIELD']) {
      $user_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
      $current_timestamp = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
      $midnight_usertimezone_datestring = MYMODULE_get_midnight_datestring("$current_timestamp", MYMODULE_get_utc_offset($user_timezone));

      $filters['field_MY_FIELD']['value']['value'] = $midnight_usertimezone_datestring;
    }
    $view->display_handler->overrideOption('filters', $filters);
  }
}
```